# Try-Catch in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

So I recently started with transactions and error handling in SQL Server in college and I've run into this issue which my teachers haven't been able to explain. When I try and execute this block:

```
Begin Transaction TRA
  Begin Try
    Alter Table history
    Add Primary Key (employee_id,date_beg)
  End Try
  Begin catch
    If @@trancount>0
    Select ERROR_NUMBER() Error, ERROR_MESSAGE() Mensaje
  End Catch
Commit
```

I get the following error messages:

> Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'history'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

So it seems the code doesn't catch the error as it's supposed to.

Would really appreciate it if you could help me!

Comment: Have you looked at any documentation on the Try ... Catch? [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175976.aspx) states that not all errors are caught...

Comment: @ChipsLetten . . . This is a level 16 error and it is run-time, not compile-time.  So, it seems like it should be caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation on TRY...CATCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175976.aspx), I think that your `CATCH` block should have caught the error.

These are the documented reasons why an error will not be caught in a `TRY...CATCH` block, none of which appear to apply to your case:

> `TRY…CATCH` constructs do not trap the following conditions:
>
> - Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of `10` or lower.
> - Errors that have a severity of `20` or higher that stop the SQL Server Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error occurs that has severity of `20` or higher and the database connection is not disrupted, `TRY…CATCH` will handle the error.
> - Attentions, such as client-interrupt requests or broken client connections.
> - When the session is ended by a system administrator by using the `KILL` statement.
>
> The following types of errors are not handled by a `CATCH` block when they occur at the same level of execution as the `TRY…CATCH` construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.

Considering the last 2 reasons in particular, this is not a compilation error, nor is it a deferred name resolution error, because your table name resolves just fine.  This really is a runtime error, and should have been caught.

And yet, even though it shouldn't be applicable here, you'll find that the following information provides a working solution for your case:

> If an error occurs during compilation or statement-level recompilation at a lower execution level (for example, when executing `sp_executesql` or a user-defined stored procedure) inside the `TRY` block, the error occurs at a lower level than the `TRY…CATCH` construct and will be handled by the associated `CATCH` block.

Applying the above information, you'll find that you can catch the error by changing your script to either of the following 2 options:

**Option 1: sp_executesql**

```
Begin Transaction TRA
  Begin Try
    exec sp_executesql 'Alter Table history Add Primary Key (employee_id,date_beg)';
  End Try
  Begin catch
    If @@trancount>0
    Select ERROR_NUMBER() Error, ERROR_MESSAGE() Mensaje
  End Catch
Commit
```

**Option 2: wrapping alter statement in a separate stored procedure**

```
create procedure WrapAlterStatementInSP as
Alter Table history Add Primary Key (employee_id,date_beg);
go

Begin Transaction TRA
  Begin Try
    exec WrapAlterStatementInSP;
  End Try
  Begin catch
    If @@trancount>0
    Select ERROR_NUMBER() Error, ERROR_MESSAGE() Mensaje
  End Catch
Commit
```

Hopefully this helps. But I do feel that there is either a bug in the current behavior, or missing information in the documentation.

Comment: How can it not be a deferred name issue? The op is creating a new object (a primary key constraint) that did not exist when the procedure was compiled. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Rachel: A deferred name resolution error would occur if the `history` table didn't exist.  OP's error is a result of *executing* the `alter` statement, not of a statement-level recompilation/deferred name resolution error.

Comment: The constraint is an object that doesn't exist though until it is created. I've had many a fun time having to force batch things like this just to force them in, just as the answer is suggesting. So your method I feel is 100% valid, its just your thoughts that it's a bug I find suspect. You should however get the magic beanz because you suggested a solution, all I did was describe the problem. Upvoted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the BOL, Try Catch will not work when:

> an error that occurs during statement-level recompilation will not
>   prevent the batch from compiling, but it will terminate the batch as
>   soon as recompilation for the statement fails. For example, if a batch
>   has two statements and the second statement references a table that
>   does not exist, deferred name resolution causes the batch to compile
>   successfully and start execution without binding the missing table to
>   the query plan until that statement is recompiled. The batch stops
>   running when it gets to the statement that references the missing
>   table and returns an error. This type of error will not be handled by
>   a TRY…CATCH construct at the same level of execution at which the
>   error occurred.

Methinx this is the issue here.